# What is meant by this notation?

Tags: calculus, notation

I found the following question:

> Let $\large f(x)=e^{x^2}$. Find and simplify $\large{f^{(3)}(x)}$.

Is it asking to find the third derivative of the function?

Which rule is used to find the derivative of e^(x^2) ? chain rule?

Comment: Yes, it is asking to find the third derivative of $f$.

Comment: Explanation of that notation is likely earlier in the same textbook.  Of course, taking the question out of the textbook can lose details like that.

Comment: Chain rule, chain rule and chain rule ! Cheers.

Comment: People use $f^{(3)}(x)$ to mean the third derivative because $f^3(x)$ usually means $f(f(f(x)))$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $f^{(3)}(x)$ denotes the third derivative of $f(x)$.

And yes, you need to use the chain rule to find $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^2}) = e^{x^2}\cdot \dfrac d{dx}(x^2)$$